# Expand/open a spinner when click on Button in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am new for Android and I am trying to expand a `Spinner` when user click on Button. As example: I have a Spinner values with 'OK' button when user click on 'ok' button then Spinner need to expands itself.

Is this possible to get a event to expand spinner hen we tapped on button?

i want show spinner like below image when we tapped on button

```
xml:-
---

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="ClickMe"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Spinner"/>

</LinearLayout>

Activity:-
----

    public class SpinnerList extends AppCompatActivity {

        String [] spinnerList = {"first","second","third"

        };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        }

        public void ClickMe(View view){

        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

its work for me 
 Spinner before = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.beforeSpinner);
before.performClick();

it will exapnd your spinner

Answer (score 0):

You can use `performClick` method of spinner to explicitly open spinner popup.

```
spinner.performClick();
```

**Edit**

```
public class SpinnerList extends AppCompatActivity {

    String [] spinnerList = {"first","second","third"};

    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    }

    public void ClickMe(View view){
        spinner.performClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Chitan rathod what i have to do inside ClickMe() method please post remaining code also because i am very new for android

Comment: As per my understanding, you want to open(expand) Spinner on your button click right?

Comment: why this line  spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner); we are not create spinner list in xml file right?

Comment: still not understandable. What is **Spinner values with 'OK'** what is spinner here? Please add good explanation, else need to flag for closing.

Comment: when user tapped on button i want to show listview as like ContextMenu how we show popupmenu in that way i want show

Comment: Then why do you want to use listview? You can simply use Spinner for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106565/discussion-between-abhiram-and-chintan-rathod).